# Music cannot play again after dispose

Tags: libgdx

Im trying to build a static `AudioManager` which is able to play any music with only referring one instance. However, the same music cannot play again after I dispose it from the instance.

The `AudioManager` works when run on desktop, but fail when run on android device.

The main function from static `AudioManager` class:

```java
Music music = null;
public static Music playMusic(String musicName){
    if (music!=null){
        music.stop();
        music.dispose();
    }

    music = assetManager.get("music/"+musicName,Music.class);
    music.setLooping(true);
    music.play();
    currentMusicName = musicName;
    MyDebugger.d("new music !");
    return music;
}
```

The changing from music_A to music_B works, but reusing music_A does not play any music with no errors. (in android device)

Any help please.

Comment: After disposing of the Music instance you can't reuse it. You must reload it. Before assetManager.get() use assetManager.load() to load the Music.

Comment: Do you have to dispose music before quitting the app at all? It's streamed, not loaded. It doesn't take memory...

Comment: @MilanG It's backed by Android's MediaPlayer, which should be released. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html#releaseplayer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are disposing your music and then trying to reuse the same music instance when you use `assetManager.get()`.

When you use AssetManager to load an asset, you should not be disposing it. You should be unloading it. That also means you cannot reuse it after unloading it. You need to load a new copy.

```
Music music = null;
public static Music playMusic(String musicName)
{

    if (music!=null){
        music.stop();
        assetManager.unload(music);
    }

    assetManager.load("music/"+musicName,Music.class);
    assetManager.finishLoading();
    music = assetManager.get("music/"+musicName,Music.class);
    music.setLooping(true);
    music.play();
    currentMusicName = musicName;
    return music;
}
```

But since you are only ever loading one music instance at a time (judging from your use of the `static` method), it might be easier not to use the asset manager at all for it.

Be careful using `static` for anything involving Disposables. Don't forget to dispose it when the game's `dispose()` is called.

Comment: Thank you! Meaning I just need to dispose once even loaded multiple different music file?

Comment: Every time you load a new music file, you need to dispose the previous one before you load a new one. But if you use asset manager, you should dispose it by calling unload on the asset manager, not by calling dispose on the music.

Comment: Understand. Thank you so much!!